# Phonegap external links doesnt work

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have an Phonegap 2.1 application, in which I use Cordova as a component.
I have set for the test my Whitelist to * and change the value that all links will be opened in the cordova webview. (when I disable this it the links are working fine)
In another project with no differences as far as I see all things work.
When I start my project on the simulator all things work fine and I get the following trace:

> 2012-09-27 11:45:02.395 rep[18416:c07] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
>   2012-09-27 11:45:02.572 rep[18416:c07] [INFO] Received Event: deviceready
>   2012-09-27 11:45:03.780 rep[18416:c07] OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set: opening in webview
>   2012-09-27 11:45:04.195 rep[18416:c07] OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set: opening in webview
>   2012-09-27 11:45:04.903 rep[18416:c07] OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set: opening in webview

But when I start on my device I get

> 2012-09-27 11:46:01.623 rep[2827:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
>   2012-09-27 11:46:04.709 rep[2827:907] OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set: opening in webview

And nothing happened, when I press again I get

> 2012-09-27 11:46:33.318 rep[2827:907] OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set: opening in webview
>   2012-09-27 11:46:33.325 rep[2827:907] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve the problem, strangely I can debug through the calls in cleaver and see how they call the load method but it dont load.
After I restart the iPad in the debugger it shows the same but it finally works, dont know why.